# Left join Linq is not working in Nopcommerce Service

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am using nopcommerce 3.4 in which i have to display all vendor list and on bases of that their resturat locations also so two tables to manipulate from Left table (Vendor) I need all records and from right table(Resturant) I need only matching records.If record is not match than display 0.

so that I have created Service of GetAllList()

```
 public virtual IPagedList<ResturantCoordinatesModel> GetAllList(int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
        {
            var Resturant = (from r in _resturantCoordinates.Table
                             select r).ToList().AsEnumerable();

            var vendor = _vendorService.GetAllVendors().ToList();
            IList<ResturantCoordinatesModel> model = new List<ResturantCoordinatesModel>();

                           var query = from v in vendor
                            join r in Resturant on v.Id equals r.VendorId into gj
                            from rt in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            orderby rt.Id
                            select new { rt.Id, v.Name, Latitude = (double?)rt.Latitude, Longitude = (double?)rt.Longitude };
}
```

but in  **var query** does not return any result.it returns **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** Error.Please Suggest for correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use by Linq

```
foreach(var v in vendor)
            {
                var s = new ResturantCoordinatesModel();
                var values = new NopDestek.StoreMapFinder.Domain.Resturant_Coordinates();

                   values = (from t in _resturantCoordinates.Table
                                  where t.VendorId == v.Id
                                  select t).FirstOrDefault();

                s.Id = v.Id;
                s.Name = v.Name;
                s.Latitude = values == null? 0 : values.Latitude;
                s.Longitude = values == null ? 0 : values.Longitude;

                model.Add(s);

            }
```

Hope This helps,

Regards,
Vinit